# Fetch label of property in Grails domain

Tags: grails, properties, field

How do I fetch the label property of a domain from messages.properties. For example, I have a domain as following

```
class Books{
    String name
    String author
    String description
    String rating
}
```

And in message.properties I have the following

```
Books.name.label=Title
Books.author.label=Author
Books.description.label=Description
Books.rating.label=Rating
```

So can I do something like

```
def fieldName = Books.name.label
```

and get 'Title' ? Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a Controller or Service, you can inject the bean

```
 def messageSource
```

and then you can call:

```
 messageSource.getMessage(code, args, defaultMsg, locale)
```